# Extjs 3 (Grid Filter)

Tags: extjs

```
fbar :[{
                    xtype       : 'datefield',
                    id          : 'date_s',
                    allowBlank  : true,
                    emptyText   : 'Choose date',
                    name        : 'deadline',
                    width       : 120,
                    editable    : false,
                },{
                    xtype       : 'button',
                    text        : 'Go!',
                    handler     : function () {
                     /*f.load({
                        params : {
                            start : 0,
                            limit : 2,
                            t : ''
                        }
                    });*/

                    var clear = f.clearFilter();
                    var searchValueDate1 = Ext.getCmp("date_s").getValue(); 
                    var date1 = searchValueDate1.format('Y-m-d); // 00:00:00');

                    //alert(date1);

                    //clear;
                    f.load().filter("question[deadline]", date1);

                    }
                }]
```

I created combobox where I can choose any date and then when I click button -> it shows only rows with only that date 9deadline date)
QUESTION: I think i wrote everything's right, but doesnt work! What is the main problem?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by doesn't work? Do you have an error?

In ExtJs 3, the filter is a widget that allow you to have a visual feature to choose a date, then, it launch an event (load) that you must trap if you need to change data before the filtering was done by the controller (in asp/php)

Something good is to give us a complete test code to simply past it in our environment

Answer (score 0):

The handler gets the button and event object passed to it. So handler should look like:

```
handler     : function (b,e) {

var theGrid = Ext.getCmp('gridId'); //You need to get the grid to filter
var theStore = theGrid.store; //Get the grid store you need it to filter

var searchValueDate1 = Ext.getCmp("date_s").getValue(); 
var date1 = searchValueDate1.format('Y-m-d); // 00:00:00');


//Filter by filters each record if true it keeps it if false it filters it out
theGrid.filterBy(function(rec){

if(rec.get('dateField') == date1 ){
  return true
}else{
 return false;
}
});

}
```

This is the basic idea a copy and paste of this won't work, it meant more as a guide.